# How to ignore "peer not authenticated" error for RemoteWebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, ssl, selenium-webdriver, remotewebdriver

My Selenium HUB is running on ssl *https*. But the certificate will be installed in a couple of days. As i am currently in the TestEnvironment, and the Selenium HUB is running on another computer within my network, i would like to **ignore** the ssl errors for now.

I am using RemoteWebDriver to connect to the HUB. But it keeps on giving me the exception: `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated`

How to ignore the error?

The HTMLUnitDriver gives a method to override this like:-

```
@Override
protected WebClient modifyWebClient(WebClient client) {
     client.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
}
```

But i need to use the RemoteWebDriver.